# Is resistor needed for Flash IC?

Tags: pcb-design, flash, rp2040

I am making my first micro controller board with the rp2040. It requires external flash and so I picked the MT25QL128ABA1EW7 since it seems to match all the requirements based on this document: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf#_supported_flash_chips.

However, in the datasheet of the flash IC, there is a two inputs(W#/DQ2) that share a pin: https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/mt25q/die-rev-a/mt25q_qlhs_l_128_aba_0.pdf#unique_10. It says the following for "This signal does not have internal pull-ups, it cannot be left floating and must be driven, even if none of W#/DQ2 function is used".

I plan to use this pin as DQ2 for the QSPI_SD2 pin from the rp2040, but I don't know if I can just connect them directly or if I need a resistor close to the DQ2 pin of the flash chip in order to prevent unwanted behavior. And if the resistor is need, how can I figure out the resistance value because it is not mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: How do existing RP2040 boards connect between MCU and flash, can you take examples from somewhere?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet: "... it cannot be left floating and must be driven..."

If you use DQ2 for the QSPI_SD2 pin then it's driven by the SPI hardware interface and you don't need to add any external pull-up resistor.

---

You must add an external pull-up resistor only if you, for some reason, leave that pin floating.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not needed.

If you look at the documentation for RP2040 boards, it does not have a separate pull-up on WP/IO2 either, for the Winbond memory.

And the Winbond memory also does not have internal pull-ups, so for the Winbond memory, the WP/IO2 must also be driven correctly, i.e. it must be high in SPI mode if you want to write to it.

The fact that there may be an internal pull-up on the RP2040 side of WP/IO2 is given in the description of possibly needing a resistor on CS for safety before internal pull-up is turned on after reset.

As always, this isn't that big a deal.

If you need a resistor and don't have it, your board may not work properly.

If you have a resistor but don't need it, it is just useless and can be left out.

And finally, if the design has a resistor and it prevents it from working, it can be removed with a soldering iron.

So do what they did for the SS pin, if you are unsure and cannot verify the need for the resistor, draw a resistor on the PCB for WP/IO2 pin but don't populate it, unless the design needs it.